# Extract line within a cell

Tags: excel, extract, cell, vba

I have information in a cell that i would like to extract only certain portion of it. There are lines within a cell seperated by a CR.

Eg. :

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
How Are you??
That is line 3
---------------------------
this is line 4
that is line 8
I want this line too
```

The above are all within a cell. And I would like to extract only line that DO NOT start with THIS or ----- or How

That is line 3
that is line 8
I want this line too

So when i run the VBA or macro i would end up with 3 lines.

Each sentence is not constant. I.e. it could be any length of words, but the first word of those that i want to truncate away is constant, i.e. starts with either This or That. Those that I want to keep is usually not constant as it's an open field keed in by users.

So i want to truncate away lines starting with --- or This or That, but keep anything else.

And this is for a whole range of cells, eg. from A1 to A100.

Hope the info i have provided is sufficient.

cheers
jeffery

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: I'd suggest you loop though each cell, look at the contents of each cell split it into an array based on the CR evaluate the first character, if - set array to "" if first 4 characters are "this" then set array to "" then loop though array setting the excel cell to the values in the array. suggestion is all I'm providing without code examples from you

Answer (score 2):

```
      Dim Arr(), FinalResult,count
range("A1").Select

for count=1 to 100
      Arr = Split(ActiveCell, vbLf)

      Dim i ,j
      For each i in Arr
          j=Mid(i,1,4)
           if Not ( j="This" or j= "this" or j= "That" or j="that" or j="----") then
              FinalResult=FinalResult & i & VbLf
           End If

      Next

      MsgBox FinalResult
Activecell.offset(1,0).select
next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for one cell. As mentioned in the second comment, you could then loop to each cell in your targeted range. What you do with the result string(s) is also up to you.

```
Public Sub GetThisAndThatLines()

  Dim sText() As String
  Dim sResult As String

  sText = Split(Selection.Text, vbLf)

  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To UBound(sText)

      If LCase(Left(sText(i), 4)) = "this" Then
          sResult = sResult + sText(i) & vbCrLf
      ElseIf LCase(Left(sText(i), 4)) = "that" Then
          sResult = sResult + sText(i) & vbCrLf
      End If

  Next

  MsgBox sResult

End Sub
```